# Bootstrap is disturbing my Table style when i use repeater

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have this piece of code i want to organized it in sequence but bootstrap  is disturbing design

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 row">
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCategoryId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CategoryId") %>' Visible="false"> </asp:Label>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/<%#Eval("imgSrc")%>" /><h5 class="text-center" />
                        <%#Eval("Category") %> </h5>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <a>
                                    <li id="liProdView" class="list-group-item">
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%#Eval("SubCategoryId","CustomerDetails.aspx?SubCategoryId={0}") %>'>
                                        <%#Eval("SubCategory") %>  ( <%#Eval("CompanyCount") %>)
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                    </li>
                                </a>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ServiceConnectionString %>"
                            SelectCommand="SELECT count(*) AS CompanyCount,dbo.tblCompanySubCategory.SubCategoryId, dbo.tblCompanySubCategory.SubCategory, 
                 dbo.tblCompanySubCategory.CategoryId  FROM dbo.tblCompany INNER JOIN dbo.tblCompanySubCategory ON 
                 dbo.tblCompany.SubCategoryId = dbo.tblCompanySubCategory.SubCategoryId
                 WHERE  (dbo.tblCompanySubCategory.CategoryId = @CategoryId)
                 GROUP BY dbo.tblCompanySubCategory.SubCategoryId, dbo.tblCompanySubCategory.SubCategory, dbo.tblCompanySubCategory.CategoryId">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter Name="CategoryId" ControlID="lblCategoryId" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="panel-footer"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" href="#">See more</a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cWD2.png)
This Is my output (screenshot) which i want to style it in rows so that when one rows complete next table must be placed in new rows in sequence

Comment: Thanks... <div style="clear: both" runat="server" Visible="<%# (Container.ItemIndex+1) % 3 == 0 %>"></div> by putting it before </ItemTemplate> ---i have solve my issue by putting restriction on repeater , now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Add the above code before the `</ItemTemplate>` That should fix the issue.

Comment: try placing it after the </ItemTemplate>

Comment: <div style="clear: both" runat="server" Visible="<%# (Container.ItemIndex+1) % 3 == 0 %>"></div> ---Thanks i have solve my issue by putting restriction on repeater , now it's in sequence